# Oracle SQL - Custom Sort

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, custom-sort

I have a scenario where I have following data:

Table: Locations

```
ID      TYPE
------------------
1000    STORE
11001   STORE
20000   STORE
1181    WAREHOUSE
12002   STORE
```

I want to sort in a way that all the IDs that end in '0000' should be sorted first, then the TYPE 'Warehouse' and then the rest of the Stores.

The desired output should be like

```
ID      TYPE
------------------
10000   STORE
20000   STORE
1181    WAREHOUSE
11001   STORE
12002   STORE
```

How do I do this custom sorting?

Comment: . . The data in your question is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I understood the problem; sample data till line #7; query begins at line #8.

```
SQL> with locations (id, type) as
  2    (select 1000 , 'STORE'     from dual union all
  3     select 11001, 'STORE'     from dual union all
  4     select 20000, 'STORE'     from dual union all
  5     select 1181 , 'WAREHOUSE' from dual union all
  6     select 12002, 'STORE'     from dual
  7    )
  8  select id, type
  9  from locations
 10  order by case when substr(to_char(id), -3) = '000' then 1 end,
 11           case when type = 'WAREHOUSE' then 2 end,
 12           type;

        ID TYPE
---------- ---------
      1000 STORE
     20000 STORE
      1181 WAREHOUSE
     12002 STORE
     11001 STORE

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression in sorting:

```
order by (case when id like '%0000' then 1
               when type = 'WAREHOUSE' then 2
               else 3
          end), id
```

This also uses `id` to sort within the three groups.

Note:  If `id` is a number and not a string, I would suggest:

```
order by (case when mod(id, 10000) = 0 then 1
               when type = 'WAREHOUSE' then 2
               else 3
          end), id
```

---

**[EDITED by LF]**

This what your ORDER BY returns, and that's not what the OP wanted:

```
SQL> with locations (id, type) as
  2    (select 1000 , 'STORE'     from dual union all
  3     select 11001, 'STORE'     from dual union all
  4     select 20000, 'STORE'     from dual union all
  5     select 1181 , 'WAREHOUSE' from dual union all
  6     select 12002, 'STORE'     from dual
  7    )
  8  select id, type
  9  from locations
 10  order by (case when id like '%0000' then 1
 11                 when type = 'WAREHOUSE' then 2
 12                 else 3
 13            end), id;

        ID TYPE
---------- ---------
     20000 STORE
      1181 WAREHOUSE
      1000 STORE
     11001 STORE
     12002 STORE

SQL>
```

Comment by Gordon:  The above should work if the 1000 row is 10000.

Comment: I think not; conditions should be separated, not part of the same CASE. At least, that's what I found out by using your ORDER BY.

Comment: @Littlefoot . . . I don't understand your comment.  Are you suggesting that ordering by 1, 2, and 3 doesn't work?

Comment: Gordon, I edited your answer and added the result. Have a look. Feel free to remove it, of course.

Comment: @Littlefoot . . . I think that is just a matter of the data being inconsistent in the question.  This answers what the OP *asked*; I assume the data is a typo.